# Why does UInt8 0x1 convert to string ☺ nodejs

Tags: node.js, encoding, buffer

btest.js

```
let b = Buffer.alloc(1);
b.writeUInt8(0x1);
console.log(b)
console.log(b.toString("utf8"));
```

console output is

```
node btest2
<Buffer 01>
☺
```

Why does b.toString() output the smiley face (U+263A) instead of Start of Heading (U+1)

Comment: Ran the code online here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php and couldn't reproduce. I highly suspect it's the console's encoding that's responsible for this behaviour, probably [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further testing I believe DPenner is correct and it is the console's encoding (ConEmu).
In cmd.exe the character displays correctly as SOH.